# Acing Levels in Little Big Planet vs. Getting 100 Percent

Tags: little-big-planet

I have found that I get 100% of the items in various levels in the first Little Big Planet, but I don't get the "Level Aced" reward. What am I not getting right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You [Ace](http://wiki.lbpcentral.com/Ace) a level by completing it without dying. (If playing with multiple people, one death will invalidate everyone from acing the level)

The [100%](http://wiki.lbpcentral.com/100%25), as you seem to have gathered, means you've collected all the prize bubbles in the level. (stickers, costumes, decorations)